# MySQL Select - Help to Select most resent row from 2 columns

Tags: mysql, select

I have the following table that stores messages between users:

[image]

I need to display a list of all last message for a users (from all users that have had contact with).

You will see to users being 1000000002 & 1000000172 for example. I need to show the last message between them which could be rows 1 to 4 - but would be 4 as last time.

I have tried the query below but its still isn't right:

```
SELECT sender_userid,receiver_userid,message,message_read,`datetime` FROM messages 
WHERE (receiver_userid='1000000172' OR sender_userid='1000000172') AND friendship_status=1 AND receiver_history=1
GROUP BY receiver_userid
ORDER BY `datetime` ASC;
```

I find the order by doesn't get the most resent - could be because its after the Group By.

Also find it treats the sender_userid & receiver_userid as different rows in the Group By. I'm unsure how to get the most resent out of both.

thankyou so very much

Answer (score 0):

Your GROUP BY should throw you errors, but MySQL just gives you garbage instead :)

You do not even need a group by, you simply want a list of all messages in which user X is involved and you want to sort them, so you have most of the work domn allready:

```
SELECT *
  FROM messages 
 WHERE (receiver_userid='1000000172' OR sender_userid='1000000172') 
   AND friendship_status=1 AND receiver_history=1
 ORDER BY `datetime` DESC;
```

Mind that you want to sort descending if you want the most recent ones first!

Comment: Actually I just want to display the last message between 2 users. The user could be sender_userid or receiver_userid column. The data is used to display the last contact as preview.

Comment: Add a TOP 1
Question is if this query shows the most recent messages as you expect. If that is teh case, just show the first record.

Answer (score 0):

use `DESC` instead of `ASC`. DESC means large one is first.